# ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant IndexController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, scaffolding

I have a project on ruby on rails and I did a scaffold, then I got an error that No route matches [GET] "/info/routes" and then I added this line to routes.db.

```
root :to => 'index#index'
```

And now it is giving me this error I cant find the solution.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant IndexController Did you mean?  IndexError):
```

Anybody knows the solution?

Comment: Well, do you have a IndexController with a index action?

Comment: it worked! Actually I was doing a API project but it was complaining that there were no index. I modified to root :to => 'alunos#index' and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was doing a API project but it was complaining that there were no index. I modified to root :to => 'alunos#index' and it worked!